# Android webview layer type flickering and scrolling issue

Tags: android, webview

In my webview, I am getting flickering and scrolling issues, If I set layer type `LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE` then scrolling works fine but view flickered while I click on button. If I set layer type `LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE` then flicker issue resolved but it causes scroll issue. Here is my code:

```
        webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            webview.getSettings().
            setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
            }
        webview.loadUrl("url");
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: on `AndroidManifest` add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` on `<application>`. Must be video loading.

Comment: Already added in manifest.

Comment: @Nik did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Please try to loadURL on UI thread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
     public void run() {
               webview.loadUrl("url");
     }
});
```

Comment: This is not a solution.